# Setting up "npm start" with a newly created React+Typescript webpack app?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

I need a bit of help with initial setup of webpack to serve my app with hot reloading. I've followed [this guide](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html) to set up React+Webpack with Typescript, but I'd like to know how I can go about setting it up so I can call "`npm start`" and have it compile and host the app, with hot reloading.

My `webpack.config.js` looks like the following:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: "production",

    // Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
    devtool: "source-map",

    resolve: {
        // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx"]
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "ts-loader"
                    }
                ]
            },
            // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "source-map-loader"
            }
        ]
    },

    // When importing a module whose path matches one of the following, just
    // assume a corresponding global variable exists and use that instead.
    // This is important because it allows us to avoid bundling all of our
    // dependencies, which allows browsers to cache those libraries between builds.
    externals: {
        "react": "React",
        "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
    }
};
```

And my `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "author": "DMW",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.4",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "^3.7.3",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "keywords": []
}
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could link me to something to get this working. I'm a bit intimidated by the search results I've found.

EDIT: I ended up using `npx create-react-app app --template typescript` instead,  as detailed here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the community. 
Regarding the settings for webpack try adding this to your package.json

```
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot"
},
```

When you do npm start, start will be taken from this script and would run app as webpack. Also --hot will ensure that hot reload is true, i.e. reload on any changes that you do to the app automatically.
Be sure to change the mode to production when pushing the app to production so that you don't get all the errors and warnings in the production. Hope it helps !!

Comment: Wow, thanks, that did indeed serve it up! But I am getting these compile errors

`ERROR in (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './emitter' in 'D:\Development\micchan\client\node_modules\webpack\hot'
 @ (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 50:18-38
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src`

Do you know why this might be?

Comment: Please put the code for your pacage.json and webpack config or edit the current one with the error as well.